# Python Parse tree IndexError : String index out of range

Tags: python, parsing, index-error

I'm coding a for parsing grammer free context project and it works for some test case (Example: read(A)), but it won't work some for say, "write a + b". It says that there is an

> IndexError: String index out of range.

It usually has this error with identifying a letter and a space after each other. I ran this with the command prompt and save both my code and `test.txt` in a folder that I `cd` to.

```
import sys

#Grammar
#<program> → <stmt list> $$
#<stmt list> → <stmt> <stmt list> | 
#<stmt> → id assign <expr> | read id | write <expr>
#<expr> → <term> <term tail>
#<term tail> → <add op> <term> <term tail> | 
#<term> → <factor> <fact tail>
#<fact tail> → <mult op> <factor> <fact tail> | 
#<factor> → lparen <expr> rparen | id | number
#<add op> → plus | minus
#<mult op> → times | div


def scanner(x):
    output = ""
    h = ""
    o = 0
    for y in range(0, len(x)):
        #h = ""
        if x[y].isspace():
            y += 1
            o=y
        elif x[y] == "(":
            output += "<term>\n"
            output += "lparen\n"
            output += "</term>\n"
            y += 1
            o=y

        elif x[y] == ":":
            if x[o+1] == "=":
                output += "assign\n"
                o=y
            else:
                print("error")
                exit()

        elif x[y] == "/":
            o=y
            if x[o+1] == "*":
                while x[y] != "*/":
                    y+=1

                    if x[y] == "*/":
                        y+=1
            else:
                o=y
                output += "<div>\n"
                output += "div\n"
                output += "</div>\n"

        elif x[y] == ")":
            output += "<term_tail>\n"
            output += "rparen\n"
            output += "</term_tail>\n"
            y += 1
            o=y

        elif x[y] == "+":
            output += "<plus>\n"
            output += x[y]+"\n"
            output += "</plus>\n"
            y += 1
            o=y

        elif x[y] == ".":
            if x[o+1].isdigit():
                y+=1
                o=y
                if x[y].isdigit():
                    y+=1
                    o = y
                else:
                    output += "number\n"
            else:
                print("error")
                exit()

        elif x[y] == "-":
            output += "<minus>\n"
            output += "minus\n"
            output += "</minus>\n"
            y += 1
            o=y

        elif x[y] == "*":
            output += "<mult_op>"
            output += "times\n"
            y += 1
            o=y

        elif x[y] == "=":

            output += "assign\n"
            y += 1
            o=y

        elif x[y].isdigit():
            if x[o+1].isdigit():
                y+=1
                o=y
            else:
                output += "number,"

        elif x[y].isalpha():
            h += x[y]
            o=y
            if x[o+1].isalpha():
                pass
            elif h == "read":
                output+= "<read>\n"
                output += h+"\n"
                output += "</read>\n"
                h = ""
                

            elif h == "write":
                output += "<write>\n"
                output += h+"\n"
                output += "</write>\n"
                h = ""

            else:
                output += "<id>\n"
                output += h+"\n"
                output += "</id>\n"
                h=""

            y += 1
            o = y
        elif x[y] == "/*":
            while x[y] != "*/":
                y+=1
            pass
        else:
            print("error")

    print(output)


def printtree(x):
    print("<Program>")
    print("   <stmt_list>")
    print("      <stmt>")
    scanner(x)
    print("      </stmt>")
    print("   </stmt_list>")
    print("</Program>")


def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        x = f.read()
    #scanner(x)
    printtree(x)


main()
```

Here is the my Traceback error from my command prompt.

```
C:\Users\sbcar\Desktop\Concepts>python ProjectTest.py test1.txt
<Program>
   <stmt_list>
      <stmt>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sbcar\Desktop\Concepts\ProjectTest.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\sbcar\Desktop\Concepts\ProjectTest.py", line 157, in main
    printtree(x)
  File "C:\Users\sbcar\Desktop\Concepts\ProjectTest.py", line 147, in printtree
    scanner(x)
  File "C:\Users\sbcar\Desktop\Concepts\ProjectTest.py", line 110, in scanner
    if x[o+1].isalpha():
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: As the posting guidelines tell you, "Make it easy for others to help you."  You've dumped your code without working to trace the problem, without isolating it, and without providing a self-contained example.  Since you've generally used meaningless variable names, you're tending to discourage potential helpers with 150 lines.  The initial debugging is *your* responsibility.

Comment: Sorry this is my first asking a question on this site but will this do? @Selcuk

Comment: if you have error with out of index in line `if x[o+1].isalpha()` then you should use what you have in `o` which you use as index - and compare `o+1` with `len(x)` - it has to be `o+1 < len(x)`. if you have `o+1 >= len(x)` then you have too big value in `o`